# Convert an NSDate's description into an NSDate?

Tags: iphone, serialization, date, nsdate

I store my NSDates to a file in the international format you get when you call description on a NSDate.

However, I don't know how to go back from the string-format to an NSDate object. NSDateFormatter seems to be limited to a couple of formats not including the international one.

How should I go back from the string-format?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Jeff is right, `NSCoding` is probably the preferred way to serialize `NSDate` objects. Anyways, if your really want/need to save the date as a plain date string this might help you:

Actually, `NSDateFormatter` isn't limited to the predefined formats at all. You can set an arbitrary custom format via the `dateFormat` property. The following code should be able to parse date strings in the "international format", ie. the format `NSDate`'s `-description` uses:

```
NSDateFormatter* dateFormatter = [[[NSDateFormatter alloc] init] autorelease];
dateFormatter.dateFormat = @"yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss ZZZ";
NSDate* date = [dateFormatter dateFromString:@"2001-03-24 10:45:32 +0600"];
```

For a full reference on the format string syntax, have a look at the [Unicode standard](http://unicode.org/reports/tr35/tr35-6.html#Date_Format_Patterns).

However, be careful with `-description` - the output of these methods is usually targeted to human readers (eg. log messages) and it is not guaranteed that it won't change its output format in a new SDK version! You should rather use the same date formatter to serialize your date object:

```
NSDateFormatter* dateFormatter = [[[NSDateFormatter alloc] init] autorelease];
dateFormatter.dateFormat = @"yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss ZZZ";
NSString* dateString = [dateFormatter stringFromDate:[NSDate date]];
```

Comment: Yes, I need cross-platform exchangeable date strings. This should solve it. Thank you!

Answer (score 4):

Instead of saving the description to a file, why not save the object itself? `NSDate` conforms to the `NSCoding` protocol; saving the object means you don't have to worry about translating it. See the [NSCoding protocol reference](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Protocols/NSCoding_Protocol) for more information.

Answer (score 0):

I would try to set up an `NSDateFormatter` to successfully parse the string by the following method:

```
- (NSDate *)dateFromString:(NSString *)string
```

Note that it could take you a while to get the `NSDateFormatter` set up just right to successfully parse your string.

If you're going to store program-facing data like this I would also recommend storing it in an easier-to-access format, e.g., [`CFAbsoluteTime`](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/CoreFoundation/Reference/CFTimeUtils/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20001452-CH1g-DontLinkElementID_15). Once you have it in your program you can format it into the international format or something else human-readable.

Answer (score 0):

Convert it to a format NSDate accepts and then perform the conversion back.

Alternatively, depending on which NSDate you're referring to (!) initWithString should cover international standard dates.

Comment: Unfortunately now, `initWithString:` is deprecated.